# combining values in rows based on matching conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple question about aggregating values in R.

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
DF <- data.frame(col1=c("Type 1", "Type 1B", "Type 2"), col2=c(1, 2, 3))
```

which looks like this:

```
     col1 col2
1  Type 1    1
2 Type 1B    2
3  Type 2    3
```

I notice that I have `Type 1` and `Type 1B` in the data, so I would like to combine `Type 1B` into `Type 1`.

So I decide to use `dplyr`:

```
filter(DF, col1=='Type 1' | col1=='Type 1B') %>%
  summarise(n = sum(col2))
```

But now I need to keep going with it:

```
DF2 <- data.frame('Type 1', filter(DF, col1=='Type 1' | col1=='Type 1B') %>%
  summarise(n = sum(col2)))
```

I guess I want to `cbind` this new DF2 back to the original DF, but that means I have to set the column names to be consistent:

```
names(DF2) <- c('col1', 'col2')
```

OK, now I can rbind:

```
rbind(DF2, DF[3,])
```

The result? It worked....

```
   col1 col2
1 Type 1    3
3 Type 2    3
```

...but ugh! That was awful! There has to be a better way to simply combine values.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possible dplyr approach:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  group_by(col1 = sub("(.*\\d+).*$", "\\1", col1)) %>%
  summarise(col2 = sum(col2))
#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#
#    col1 col2
#1 Type 1    3
#2 Type 2    3
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `sub()` with `aggregate()`, removing anything other than a digit from the end of `col1`,

```
do.call("data.frame", 
    aggregate(col2 ~ cbind(col1 = sub("\\D+$", "", col1)), DF, sum)
)
#     col1 col2
# 1 Type 1    3
# 2 Type 2    3
```

The `do.call()` wrapper is there so that the first column after `aggregate()` is properly changed from a matrix to a vector. This way there aren't any surprises later on down the road.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(transform(DF, col1=gsub("(.*)[A-Z]+$","\\1",DF$col1)))[,list(col2=sum(col2)),col1]

#      col1 col2
# 1: Type 1    3
# 2: Type 2    3
```

---

Or even more directly:

```
setDT(DF)[, .(col2 = sum(col2)), by = .(col1 = sub("[[:alpha:]]+$", "", col1))]
```

Comment: There has got to be a more generalizable way to do something so simple, no? Surely such a simple operation shouldn't have to include regex type matching!!

Comment: In one line now. But you will need `gsub` or find another pattern to recognize that `type 1` and `type1B` are similar. The aggregating can be done with `aggregate`, `dplyr`, `data.table` ,etc.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, `aggregate()` is the perfect function for this purpose, but you shouldn't have to do any text processing (e.g. `gsub()`). I would do this in a two-step process:

1. Overwrite `col1` with the new desired grouping.
2. Compute the aggregation using the new `col1` to specify the grouping.

---

```
DF$col1 <- ifelse(DF$col1 %in% c('Type 1','Type 1B'),'Type 1',levels(DF$col1));
DF;
##     col1 col2
## 1 Type 1    1
## 2 Type 1    2
## 3 Type 2    3
DF <- aggregate(col2~col1, DF, FUN=sum );
DF;
##     col1 col2
## 1 Type 1    3
## 2 Type 2    3
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer since it avoids mashing around with text. It keeps the complexity low.