# R: combine content multiple rows of column X based on ID in column Y

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R that consists of two columns, like this:

```
x <- data.frame("gene" = c('gene1', 'gene2', 'gene3', 'gene3', 'gene4', 'gene5', 'gene5'), "info" = c('A1','B2','A45','B89','A1','C46','D89'))
x
```

The dataframe looks like this:

> ```
>    gene info
> 1 gene1   A1
> 2 gene2   B2
> 3 gene3  A45
> 4 gene3  B89
> 5 gene4   A1
> 6 gene5  C46
> 7 gene5  D89
> ```

You will notice that the gene column has several entries with the same name (gene 3 and gene 5). I want to change this so that each gene only takes one row. I thus would like to restructure the dataframe into something like this:

> ```
>    gene info
> 1 gene1   A1
> 2 gene2   B2
> 3 gene3   A45,B89
> 4 gene4   A1
> 5 gene5   C46,D89
> ```

I have no idea how to go about this. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500535/combining-values-in-rows-based-on-matching-conditions-in-r) that was about something similar. There, they had to take the sum of the different rows, but I simply want to put the info values of rows with identical gene IDs next to each other.

Anyone any idea how to go about this? I am currently working in R, but a bash solution would also be helpful.

Thanks already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple base R option is using `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(info ~ gene, x, c)
   gene     info
1 gene1       A1
2 gene2       B2
3 gene3 A45, B89
4 gene4       A1
5 gene5 C46, D89
```

Comment: yep, cleaner than my solution!

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, .(info = toString(info)), gene]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use dplyr for this:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarize(info = paste(info, collapse =','))
```

That gives you

```
  gene  info   
  <chr> <chr>  
1 gene1 A1     
2 gene2 B2     
3 gene3 A45,B89
4 gene4 A1     
5 gene5 C46,D89
```

Comment: I like the dplyr idea - but it unfortunately did not work on my actual dataset ... (which is formatted in the same way as the dummy dataset I posted above).