# How do I fix 'mutate()' error in simple 'stringr' regex code

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, stringr, mutate

I am trying to sort through a Trinotate RNA-seq output file in R to extract all gene ontology terms (i.e., GO:00057) associated with gene IDs (i.e.,TRINITY_DN142883_c0_g1) from a long string of mixed character/numeric characters. I'm using 'dplyr' and 'strings'.

My data looks like this:

| Gene | GOX |
| --- | --- |
| TRINITY_DN142883_c0_g1 | GO:0003779^molecular_function^actin binding`GO:0045886^biological_process^negative regulation of synaptic assembly at neuromuscular junction`GO:0016567^biological_process^protein ubiquitination |
| TRINITY_DN142917_c0_g1 | GO:0016020^cellular_component^membrane`GO:0000325^cellular_component^plant-type vacuole`GO:0005886^cellular_component^plasma membrane`GO:0005774^cellular_component^vacuolar membrane`GO:0005773^cellular_component^vacuole`GO:0004016^molecular_function^adenylate cyclase activity`GO:0015079^molecular_function^potassium ion transmembrane transporter activity`GO:0006813^biological_process^potassium ion transport |

my code is this (I'm trying to remove all words from 'GOX' column so that only GO terms remain):

```
practice%>%
  select(GOX)%>%
  mutate(col=str_replace_all(practice,"\\w",""))
```

Depending on the size of my data frame (2 vs 10 rows), I get different errors:

```
Error 1: Warning message:
There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
ℹ In argument: `col = str_replace_all(practice, "\\w", "")`.
Caused by warning in `stri_replace_all_regex()`:
! argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

OR Error 2:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `col = str_replace_all(practice, "\\w", "")`.
Caused by error:
! `col` must be size 10 or 1, not 2.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I've looked over stack overflow, and there seem to be similar errors but the fixes don't seem appropriate (i.e., this data doesn't have missing values, I believe the data.frame format is appropriate for str_replace_all as long it is used with 'dplyr', etc). Maybe this is caused by all of the symbols in my 'GOX' column? I'd appreciate any help, and I'm open to completely different techniques as I'm pretty unexperienced with regex.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `str_replace_all` only works with vectors and not dataframes. `practice` is a dataframe and not a name of a column. Also select columns that you need to manipulate. You selected `GOX` yet you do not use it anywhere. perharps you need `...%>%mutate(col = str_replace_all(GOX, '\\w', ''))` you could use `str_remove_all(GOX, '\\w')` instead

Comment: That fixed the errors, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take the opposite approach and keep only those terms that match your pattern.  `str_extract_all` followed by `unnest` also has the advantage of putting your data in [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) format, which will most likely help with downstream processing.

The `select(-GOX)` is there only to assist in formating the result nicely.

Assume your data frame is `df`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(GOTerm = str_extract_all(GOX, "(GO:\\d+)")) %>% 
  unnest(GOTerm) %>% 
  select(-GOX)
# A tibble: 11 × 2
   Gene                   GOTerm   
   <chr>                  <chr>     
 1 TRINITY_DN142883_c0_g1 GO:0003779
 2 TRINITY_DN142883_c0_g1 GO:0045886
 3 TRINITY_DN142883_c0_g1 GO:0016567
 4 TRINITY_DN142917_c0_g1 GO:0016020
 5 TRINITY_DN142917_c0_g1 GO:0000325
 6 TRINITY_DN142917_c0_g1 GO:0005886
 7 TRINITY_DN142917_c0_g1 GO:0005774
 8 TRINITY_DN142917_c0_g1 GO:0005773
 9 TRINITY_DN142917_c0_g1 GO:0004016
10 TRINITY_DN142917_c0_g1 GO:0015079
11 TRINITY_DN142917_c0_g1 GO:0006813
```

Comment: That is very helpful, thanks! Is there a way to get all of the GO terms associated with a particular Gene ID into the same row? I.e., GO:0003779 GO:0045886 GO:0016567 etc?

Comment: You're right, I realized too late to edit my first comment.

Comment: Yes: see `pivot_wider`.  However, I advise against this - it will most likely make your workflow harder.  For example, what if `"GO:0003779"` is the "first" GO Term for one Gene ID and the "third" for another, and you want to see all the Gene IDs associated with  `"GO:0003779"`?

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for the advice. For posterity, if someone did want to do so this appeared to work: "p<-aggregate(GOTerm~Gene,p,c)" from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286654/r-combine-content-multiple-rows-of-column-x-based-on-id-in-column-y . Thanks everyone for your help!